# Removing JARS from InteliJ IDEA JDK classpath

Tags: android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, android-source

I am trying to build AOSP on Ubuntu using InteliJ IDEA. One of the steps mentioned in setup instructions is to remove JARs from your JDK's classpath, making it no lib JDK.

On **InteliJ**  I am unable to do so. Once I add the the JDK this is how the class path looks like: 
[image]

How to fullfill 'No Lib' setup requirement? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Delete all entries from the classpath. JDK 9+ doesn't have jars, but uses modules instead. If you want to see the jars, switch to JDK 8.

Comment: I can't delete the modules as well.

Comment: Did you try JDK 8 with the jars?

Comment: Yes, with 1.8 I can remove JARS.